# How to add a scroll bar to my table?

Tags: html, css

I want to my table to have a scroll bar so that the page will not have too height and i tried many answers that i've searched but nothing is happening. here is my code.

```
  <div class="text">List Of Product </div>
  <div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable">
<thead class="fixedHeader">
<tr>
 <th>Image</th>
 <th>Item Name</th>
 <th>Item Price</th>
 <th>Item Description</th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $ble = $row2['id'];
        $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM athan_products where product_id='$ble'");
        echo '<tbody class="scrollContent">';
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) {
            echo '<td class="templatemo_pizza_box"><img alt="Motor" src="images/motor/'       . $row3['product_photo'] . '" width="65px" height="65px" /></a></td>';
            echo '<td class="textbox"> ' . $row3['partsname'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td class="textbox"> ' . $row3['price'] . ' </td>';
            echo '<td class="textbox"> ' . $row3['description'] . '     </td>';
                                                                      echo '<td><a rel="facebox" href=portal.php?id=' .      $row3["product_id"] . '><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"/></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        echo "</tbody>";
    }
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS: `table{ overflow: auto; height: 100px; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the element you want to scroll u need to give height, and what happens when it overflows that height.
For example:

```
<table style="height:20px;overflow-y:scroll">....</table>
```

Will cause the table to have scrollbars when content is over 20px in height

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your table in a `<div class="table-wrapper">...</div>`

The CSS for the table wrapper would then be....

```
div.table-wrapper {
  max-height: 400px; /* max height for the table */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simple to use in css:**

```
table{ overflow-y:scroll;height: 200px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work. please try this code.

```
    <table style="height:20px; overflow-y:scroll" wirdth="2px">
<tr>     
<th>hello</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>one</td> 
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
</tr>
    </table>
```